# How to use data created in one ViewModel on another Page/Viewmodel?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp, win-universal-app

I'm currently building the UI for the app I'm working on and I have a few problems with the bindings.

The Scenario:

I have a pivot control with every pivot element consisting of an extra Frame/Page.
Now I have a TextBlock on the first PivotItem. I bind this to a "string" and use a button to switch between two possible contents of the button.

When the button is on the same Page/Frame it works like a charm. But when I implement a button on the MainPage and implement the same `Viewmodel` for the MainPage then it doesn't work. It will only change the string content on the MainPage.

Is it possible to implement the change for every Page/Frame?

And when that is done I have a Page where I gather data with a serial port.
I save the data to a List and I want to be able to use this list from 2 different Pages/Frames.
Thinking about the scenarion above then it would probably gather the data for the page where I have the button to get the data but it would probably display nothing on the other page. 
How can I build it like I want it to be?

**Here is a short example:**

**Mainpage.xaml**

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Height="50" Width="200" Content="Change" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="50 50 0 0" Click="{x:Bind MainViewModel.Change}"/>

    <Pivot x:Name="MainPivot" Margin="50 50">
        <PivotItem Header="Page 1">
            <Frame x:Name="Page1" />
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
</StackPanel>
```

**Mainpage.xaml.cs**

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Page1.Navigate(typeof(Page1));

    ViewModel = new MainViewModel();
}
public MainViewModel ViewModel { get; private set; }
```

**Page1.xaml**

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.StringModel.String1, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" />

    <Button Content="Change" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold" Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.Change}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**Page1.xaml.cs**

```
public Page1()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    ViewModel = new MainViewModel();
}

public MainViewModel ViewModel { get; private set; }
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
private StringModel _stringModel = new StringModel();

public StringModel StringModel
{
    get => _stringModel;
    set
    {
        if (_stringModel != value)
        {
            _stringModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

public void Change()
{
    if (StringModel.String1 == "Text1")
    {
        StringModel.String1 = "Text2";
    }
    else
    {
        StringModel.String1 = "Text1";
    }   
}
```

**StringModel.cs**

```
private string _string1 = "XXX";

    public string String1
    {
        get => _string1;
        set
        {
            _string1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are missing a "service layer" or "business layer" of your application. You need an external class which manages the data, and can provide models to populate your ViewModels:

[image]

I'd suggest using some kind of dependency injection, so each of your page view models have a reference to the `DataProvider` service class. This class does the serial port work to get a list of models, and provides an interface for getting data and pushing any updates to the ViewModels.

A good way of handling *events* that are shared, like say a "load data" button that may appear on different view models is an [Event Aggregator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx). A service that can be injected into classes where events can be raised or subscribed to across the application.

Answer (score 1):

Generally children of a XAML parent inherit the binding context of said parent.
So not sure you need to hook up a VM to your frame.

But suppose it does not work with Frames, you are creating a new MainViewModel for the frame as for the mainpage!

The solution here would be to create a singleton MainViewModel and get a hold of that one to hook up the `BindingContext`.

Comment: Ok I managed to implement the singleton and this solved my first problem. I still have to implement it in the serial port project but I'm quite confident that it can work. Thanks so far :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Publisher-Subscriber pattern (Pub-Sub).

Already explained this here: [Communication Between Views in MVVM (Pub-Sub Pattern)](http://www.codearsenal.net/2013/07/pub-sub-observer-pattern-in-mvvm.html)